# find and save words from 2 files

Tags: bash, parsing, text-parsing

I have 2 txt file's with words (1.txt and 2.txt)

1.txt

```
abc
cda
sda
era
```

2.txt

```
krt
gor
abc
sda
rtr
```

How can I obtain a list of the words that are in both 1.txt and 2.txt?

EXAMPLE of what i need to obtain as a result

output.txt

```
abc
sda
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use GNU grep:

```
grep -wf file1 file2
```

or

```
grep -wf file2 file1
```

Output:

```
abc
sda
```

Comment: How can I save the output into a file.txt without printing them? Thank you

Comment: Use output redirection: `grep -wf file1 file2 > foo.txt`

Answer (score 1):

```
sort 1.txt 2.txt |uniq -d
```

provided each 1.txt and 2.txt is deduplicated. If they aren't then:

```
(sort -u 1.txt && sort -u 2.txt) | sort | uniq -d
```

Both versions are POSIX compliant.

Comment: This won't produce correct results if there are duplicates in either file.

Comment: @PSkocik How can I save the output into a file.txt without printing them? Thank you!

Comment: Put ` >file.txt ` somewhere after the last `|`

Comment: @BlueMoon Yeah, I get what you mean. There aren't duplicates in his  source files though. If he had duplicates, he can always deduplicate them first: `(sort -u 1.txt; sort -u 2.txt) | sort |uniq -d`